# Netbeans 8.2 not responding

Tags: netbeans, java-9

I am brand new to computer programming for CIS 210 and it's off to terrible start. Downloaded JDK 9 and Netbeans 8.2. Netbeans won't let me open a new project or file. No error message or anything, almost as if I'm not clicking it. Screen remains blank as seen in the link below. It's driving me insane.

Blank Screen when I click on new project:

[image]

Comment: Not very clear though and some logs or info would have added to it. But you can still get through http://wiki.netbeans.org/JDK9Support and check if it helps you in some sort.

Comment: Unless you are required to use Java 9, don't. It's just a few days old and it will take a while until everything works flawlessly. Stick to Java 8 instead.

Comment: This OP is similar to several other questions on using Java 9 with NetBeans, but since the symptom of the problem was different in this post, and there are currently problems downloading the Dev Build of NetBeans, I thought it merited an answer. Just linking to other posts would not have been helpful.

Comment: @Andrew Hitchcock you need to mark correct answer accepted and help other to know correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

If you had Netbeans installation over **Java 9** then Please note *Netbeans does not work with Java 9*. Proof: [https://forums.netbeans.org/topic68000.html][1]

The solution is for Windows, but the same logic applied in Linux too.

**Solution1:**
You have to edit `netbeans.conf` find to your java installation path. You can find `netbeans.conf` inside `etc` folder of Netbeans installation folder.

Make your `netbeans.conf` like below.
Eg, `netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_144"`

Answer (score 3):

NetBeans 8.2 does not support Java 9. It just won't work.

The solution is to download the latest nightly build of NetBeans, which does support Java 9:

- Normally you would go to the [NetBeans download page](https://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html) and click the [Development](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/) link in the top right corner of the screen.
- However, I just tried that and it looks like their web page for downloading nightly builds is not working properly at the moment due to "*...violates the following Content Security Policy directive...*" errors. I've never seen that before.
- A temporary workaround for that problem is to go directly to [Index of /download/trunk/nightly/latest/bundles/](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/bundles/) and select the download that is appropriate for your environment. You should be able to parse the file names to work out which one you want, depending on whether you need 32-bit or 64-bit, whether you are running on Mac OS or Linux or Windows, etc. (To be clear, ignore this bullet point if the Development link in the first bullet point above is working properly.)

Also note that you can safely install and run multiple versions of NetBeans concurrently: use version 8.2 for Java 8 development, and use the Development Version of NetBeans for Java 9 development.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Update:

The page for [downloading Development Builds of NetBeans](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/) is working again, so go there, select your **Platform** from the droplist, and then click the appropriate **Download** button.

NetBeans with Java 9 is working fine for me using that approach.

Answer (score 2):

**[NetBeans 9](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeans_9)** would be supported version for Java 9, which was supposed to be released by **[Aug 2017](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/roadmap.html)**

> NetBeans 9 will be released from Apache Software Foundation as new
>   Apache project. NetBeans is being donated to ASG by Oracle. **NetBeans
>   9 main theme will be to support this upcoming Java SE 9 release.**

Of course, you can use [NetBeans daily build](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/bundles/), but there won't be guarantee of it's stability.

Comment: Sadly, I can't find any future target date for the release of NetBeans 9. But a Dev Build with Java 9 has been working fine for me.